# Robust Azure Storage Library (CloudBlob, PageBlob) for Silverlight or Javascript

Tags: javascript, silverlight, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm looking for a robust Azure storage library that can access pageblobs and regular blobs, with as much error checking and features as the standard library.

I'm especially interested in using Shared Access Signatures with PageBlobs with either solution.  Core features I need for to my application are

- Listing page blobs and parsing the XML that lists active pages
- Searching the blobs using a flat hierarchy
- Processing the results as a binary stream

Answer (score 0):

Since Microsoft's Storage Client library is a wrapper over REST API for storage (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179355.aspx), you may want to write your own wrapper to suit your needs. A good starting point would be David Pallman's Azure Storage Sample project on CodePlex (http://azurestoragesamples.codeplex.com/) or Neil's blog on Windows Azure REST API (http://convective.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/examples-of-the-windows-azure-storage-services-rest-api/)